# Auto typer is holding CTRL + enter

Tags: c#, sendkeys

Im coding a feature in a C# program that automatically pastes text to anywhere.

Im giving it the following text to paste: "aaaaaaaaaIm"

And im pasting it like this.

```
writeText("aaaaaaaaaIm", true);

private void writeText(String text, Boolean type)
    {
        if (!type)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { SendKeys.Send(text.ToString()); });
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { SendKeys.Send(c.ToString()); });
                Random random = new Random();
                Int32 delay = random.Next(100, 350);
                Thread.Sleep(delay);
            }
        }
    }
```

This works fine, but the program im pasting to, has a shortcut of CTRL + Enter, which is firing, when im not typing this. So I use an online keyboard checker site to see which keys are being pressed and here is the result

[image: keyboard checker]

so the text "aaaaaaaaaIm" is being typed but also CTRL + enter
Some text doesn't set this off, and only types what I give it. Im not sure if theres a specific character setting this off or anything

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why are you Invoking there? Theres's no need for it. Remove that. What kind of application is this? Have you added `<appSettings><add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/</appSettings>` to `app.config` to make sure you're using the correct implementation of `SendInput()`. -- Make these changes and try again. You're not sending `^~` anywhere in this code. Move the `Random` declaration outside the loop, as the first line of the method. -- If you want this method to run asynchronously (you can do nothing in the meanwhile, though) change in `private async Task WriteText()` and `await Task.Delay()`.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks Jimmy, its running on its own thread and I would get errors without the invoking. The error was because I was reading the contents of a .txt file instead of using the string like I am here which works, I thought I could substitute it since they both looked identical. I think my .txt files have a hidden /n which I cant see, as the first character, when printed, is blank but goes to the next line.

Comment: As already mentioned, there's no need of a Thread or Invoking. Since you already have IO operations, use the async/await pattern (if needed, you should also describe the context of these operations). Now, why do you post code that cannot reproduce the problem? Describe the actual operations and post a sample of the file content, the code that reads it and specify the Encoding used to store the strings you're using.